# How WhatsApp receive Push Notification when app is killed (Need to implement in flutter)

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
Don't dislike my Questions, explain how other apps are doing or how I can achieve this.
```

I want to know how `WhatsApp` and `Instagram` similar apps received notifications when the app is `closed` or `killed`. Even if I restart my device and enable Wi-Fi it automatically start showing new notification in real-time.

I don't want FCM (Firebase Push Notification) because I am creating a chat app in **Flutter** (android/ios) that needs instant push notification for a real-time chat even app is killed or the device restarted. And neither background service because if I restart my device background service will stop running.

I want solutions like WhatsApp, Snapchat, and Instagram for `real-time chat push notifications` for a chat in a flutter

.

Comment: They are using a background service. It works after restarts because they also register an onRestart listener, that restarts that background service after the device restarts.

Comment: `Don't dislike my Questions, explain how other apps are doing or how I can achieve this.` this is going to have the opposite effect from what you might expect unfortunately, your question seems to be asking for suggestions to software which is probably why people would dislike it